# Stream map error: type mismatch

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and I would like to write the following Java code in Scala.

Java code:

```
Files
 .walk(Paths.get("R:\\scala"))
 .filter(p-> isRegularFile(p))
 .map(Path::getFileName)
 .map(Path::toString)
 .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am having trouble understandning the following error message for the Scala code below. What am I supposed to change? If I use the _ notation I get more errors:

```
Error:(12, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.function.Function[java.nio.file.Path,String]
 required: java.util.function.Function[? >: ?0, ?]
Note: java.nio.file.Path <: ? >: ?0, but Java-defined trait Function is 
invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: ? >: ?0`. (SLS 3.2.10)
     .map(new java.util.function.Function[Path, String]() {
```

Scala code:

```
Files
 .walk(Paths.get("R:\\scala"))
 .filter(isRegularFile(_))
 .map(new java.util.function.Function[Path,Path](){
   def apply(p:Path): Path = p.getFileName
 })
 .map(new java.util.function.Function[Path,String](){
   def apply(p:Path):String = p.toString
 })
 .forEach(println(_))
```

Answer (score 4):

Scala is having a hard time inferring types in this case (would love to hear why from smarter people than me). Meanwhile, you can help the Scala compiler by annotating your `.map` methods with type hints:

```
Files
  .walk(Paths.get("R:\\scala"))
  .filter(isRegularFile(_))
  .map[Path](new java.util.function.Function[Path,Path](){
    def apply(p:Path): Path = p.getFileName
  })
  .map[String](new java.util.function.Function[Path,String](){
    def apply(p:Path):String = p.toString
  })
  .forEach(println(_))
```

By the way, if you are using Scala 2.12, then you can replace `java.util.function.Function` with single abstract method, making your code look like:

```
Files
  .walk(Paths.get("R:\\scala"))
  .filter(isRegularFile(_))
  .map[Path]((p: Path) => p.getFileName)
  .map[String]((p: Path) => p.toString)
  .forEach(println(_))
```

Comment: You saved my day. Spend so many hours struggled with this obscure error message.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but the scala compiler for some reason cannot infer the result types of the `.map` steps. If you ascribe the types explicitly, it works (tested on scala 2.12.4):

```
import java.util.function.{Function => JFunction}
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, Path}

Files.
  walk(Paths.get("/usr/bin")).
  filter(Files.isRegularFile(_)).
  map[Path](new JFunction[Path, Path]() {
    def apply(p:Path): Path = p.getFileName
  }).
  map[String](new JFunction[Path, String](){
    def apply(p:Path): String = p.toString
  }).
  forEach(println(_))
```

Note that you can probably[1] abbreviate it as follows:

```
Files.
  walk(Paths.get("/usr/bin")).
  filter(Files.isRegularFile(_)).
  map[Path](_.getFileName).
  map[String](_.toString).
  forEach(println)
```

[1] The `println(_)` notation seems to imply that you are on 2.12.x anyway. I'm not sure about 2.11.x, especially < 2.11.5.