# Using Comparator from Scala

Tags: scala, function

What's wrong with using `Comparator` from Scala? The invocation is not compiled:

```
java.util.Comparator.comparing(
      new java.util.function.Function[String, java.math.BigInteger] {
        override def apply(t: String) = new java.math.BigInteger(t)
})
```

https://ideone.com/OdHvBU

The error message is very unclear.

```
Main.scala:3: error: overloaded method value comparing with alternatives:
  [T, U <: Comparable[_ >: U]](x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: T, _ <: U])java.util.Comparator[T] <and>
  [T, U](x$1: java.util.function.Function[_ >: T, _ <: U], x$2: java.util.Comparator[_ >: U])java.util.Comparator[T]
 cannot be applied to (java.util.function.Function[String,java.math.BigInteger])
    java.util.Comparator.comparing(
                         ^
```

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to agree with you: the error message is not very clear.

This here works:

```
java.util.Comparator.comparing[String, java.math.BigInteger](
  new java.util.function.Function[String, java.math.BigInteger] {
    override def apply(t: String) = new java.math.BigInteger(t)
  }
)
```

What happens is: for some strange reason it cannot infer what the type parameter `U` is so that it's `Comparable`. You have to explicitly write out that you are comparing `BigInteger`s. I'm not sure about *why*, but it seems to be a common issue with generic java methods ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954950/stream-map-error-type-mismatch/48955125#48955125) is another similar example that I've seen just recently).